# Emacs Package Install Minibuffer

Tags: spacemacs, package

I'm trying to get the same functionality as in spacemacs where package-install gives you a list of packages with fuzzy search. Pretty much smex for package-install. That way even if I don't know the exact name, I can still install the package. However, when I search this all I get are issues installing other packages.

Edit:
Here's a picture of what I would like:
[image: spacemacs package install]. I would like fuzzy search combined with a menu instead of just a minibuffer for package-install

Comment: Your question is unclear: you vaguely say what behavior you want, and you say you can get it in Spacemacs, but you don't say in which other context you want it.  Also you say you "get issues" but don't say what are those.  Finally, note that the default completion in Emacs accepts `*` for glob-patterns, so you can type `*py TAB` to see packages whose name includes `py`.

Comment: Fair enough. When I search for this exact feature, I get other, unrelated posts about having trouble installing packages. This is not related to my question

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are looking for a completion frontend such as [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) or [helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/), which overrides `completing-read-function` and related minibuffer/in-buffer completion options to provide "fuzzy" completion almost everywhere in Emacs. Enabling such modes automatically makes the `M-x package-install RET` completion session use "fuzzy" filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ivy and I get the fuzzy search feature you seek. In general ivy is really nice, and offers smex-like completion in a lot of places, including M-x.

[image: install-package]

You can install and try it with (if you use use-package) with:

```
(use-package ivy
:ensure t
:diminish (ivy-mode)
:config
(ivy-mode 1))
```

and then run M-x package-install. Also worth knowing in ivy completions spaces are considered as any character so "ha de" is valid search for "haskell-mode".

Spacemacs defaults to helm narrowing framework that also offers similar capabilities but personally I prefer ivy.

Answer (score 0):

One package that may provide you with the intended behavior is `ido-ubiquitous`.

Install it with:
`package-install RET ido-ubiquitous`

Activate it with:
`(require 'ido-ubiquitous)`
`(ido-ubiquitous-mode)`

Disclaimer: After I just installed it, the package says the following:

> Warning (ido-ubiquitous): The ido-ubiquitous package is now redundant. All functionality, including ido-ubiquitous-mode, has been merged into the ido-completing-read+ package. You should replace ido-ubiquitous with ido-completing-read+ in your Emacs config. For more information, see:
>   https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous#version-40-changes

So the functionality may be moved to an other package.

Comment: I'm not a Spacemacs user, so I could very easily be wrong, but [its documentation](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION#completion) suggests the behaviour OP is looking for is provided by one of [Helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) or [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), not `ido-completing-read-plus`. You could, of course, still recommend `ido-completing-read-plus`, but you should the distinction clear in your answer.

Comment: Neither helm nor ivy did a completion after the  ’package-install’ command

Comment: I don't follow. Helm and Ivy don't instigate completion; they change its behaviour and presentation. It is the `package-install` command which instigates completion by calling `completing-read`. Try this: 1. `emacs -Q` 2. `M-x package-initialize RET` 3. `M-x ivy-mode RET` OR `M-x helm-mode RET` 4. `M-x package-install RET`. You should get a completion session not too unlike the picture in the OP.

Comment: If one installs a package (say `ido-ubiquitous`) in spacemacs without explicitly pulling it in via a layer, spacemacs will uninstall it at next startup or on `SPC f e R`.

Comment: @Basil You are well right. I am not a Spacemacs user but GNU Emacs. If there are some fundamental differences in package handling please feel free to edit my answer so it fits Spacemacs specifications.

Comment: @DanielHitzel The only thing I disagree with is your statement "The package is called `ido-ubiquitous`." You could instead write something along the lines of "You may be interested in trying `ido-ubiquitous`," before proceeding to describe it and its merits.

Comment: I edited my answer based on you proposals. Thanks for the input.